# How to assign multiple variables in parallel in shell

Tags: bash, shell, parallel-processing, sh

ATM my current thoughts are, to do it like this:

```
a_NODE=$(node -v) &
a_NPM=v$(npm -v) &
a_YARN=v$(yarn -v) &
a_CURL=v$(curl --version | head -n 1 | awk '{ print $2 }') &
wait
echo "Node:             $a_NODE"
echo "NPM:              $a_NPM"
echo "YARN:             $a_YARN"
echo "curl:             $a_CURL"
```

But this actually skips all the variable definitions and prints empty version strings. AFAIK the `wait` command should make the script wait untill all of the varbiables are set and just then go over to printing - but it doesn't.

Comment: Background commands run in a subshell, so the assignments don't affect the original shell.

Comment: when you put a process in the background you are actually spawning a new standalone process; and while the current process may be referred to as the *parent* process there is no interaction between the two processes which means when the background process exits, any assignments made in that process disappear with the process; to feed the results of the *child* processes back to the parent process you'll need to implement some sort of interprocess communications (eg, files, pipes, sockets, etc)

Comment: You could have each command write to temporary files. Then assign the variables from the files after they're all done.

Comment: @ufopilot He does if he wants to run the commands concurrently.

Comment: It says it right there in the title: "in parallel"

Comment: I assume these trivial `-v` commands are just minimal examples, the real commands do take time so it's worth running them in parallel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Background commands run in subshells, so the variable assignments aren't in the original shell process.

Redirect the outputs to files, and read those files in the main shell.

```
node -v > /tmp/node.$$ &
npm -v > /tmp/npm.$$ &
yarn -v > /tmp/yarn.$$ &
curl --version | head -n 1 | awk '{ print $2 }' > /tmp/curl.$$ &
wait
a_NODE=$(</tmp/node.$$)
a_NPM=$(</tmp/npm.$$)
a_YARN=$(</tmp/yarn.$$)
a_CURL=$(</tmp/curl.$$)
rm -f /tmp/{node,npm,yarn,curl}.$$
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked :) Just a sidequestion: can I store the output in variables and not in files?

Comment: No, that's the whole problem.

Answer (score 1):

@Barmar's answer is probably the correct for this particular question. If you have more than just 4 jobs you want to run in parallel, a better solution is to use `parset`:

```
$ parset myarr -j 8 'echo Job {#}; echo arguments {}' ::: a b c ::: X Y Z ::: 1 2 3
$ echo ${myarr[5]}
Job 6 arguments a Y 3
```

`parset` will basically do what @Barmar does, but will also clean up tmp-files if the command crashes.

https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parset.html